# angularJS translate strings failing to load

Tags: angularjs, translate

I am using angular 1.5 and using translate to externalize my strings to a separate json file.
The translated strings sometimes fail to load and the path of the string is displayed instead.
ex: instead of displaying "Hello World" it displays something like "greet.hello".

This is not a regular occurrence and goes away when I refresh the page.
Not sure whether this is a file load issue.

Comment: Are you using bind once? Add your HTML

Comment: Im using something like this

Comment: <h1> {{'greet.hello' | translate}} </h1>

Comment: Does `greet` make reference to your controller alias in the view?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the single quote.

Its should be {{greet.hello | translate}}.

it's better practice to use directive.

Angular runs every single filter **twice** per $digest cycle once something has changed.

So you can do directive instead:

```
   <h1 translate="{{greet.hello}}" ></h1>
```